# Turf returns wrong (?) bearing and distance

Tags: reactjs, turfjs, azimuth

In my react app I have this piece of code:

```
import * as turfBearing from '@turf/bearing'
import * as turfDistance from '@turf/distance'

  distance( p1, p2 ) {
    return Math.round( turfDistance.default( p1, p2 ) * 1000 )
  }

  bearing( p1, p2 ) {
    return ( Math.round( turfBearing.default( p1, p2 ) ) + 360 ) % 360
  }
```

Given the data:

```
const p1 = [ 48.1039072, 11.6558318 ]
const p2 = [ 48.1035817, 11.6555873 ]
```

The results are:

```
bearing = 233, dist = 45
```

If I feed the same data to an online service like https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/azimuth it gives results:

[image]

which are considerably different from turf's.

Is this turf's problem or online calculator's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Turfjs has some problems in calc. I swapped it for a randomly picked library `"sgeo": "^0.0.6"`, and the code:

```
distance( p1, p2 ) {
  return Math.round( new sgeo.latlon( ...p1 ).distanceTo( new sgeo.latlon( ...p2 ) ) * 1000 )
}

bearing( p1, p2 ) {
  return Math.round( new sgeo.latlon( ...p1 ).bearingTo( new sgeo.latlon( ...p2 ) ) )
}
```

produces relevant results:

```
bearing = 206 dist = 40
```

Comment: I'd also highly recommend `geodesy` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/geodesy)

Answer (score 1):

Turf expects data in (longitude, latitude) order per the GeoJSON standard, see https://github.com/Turfjs/turf#data-in-turf

In your case input data should be:

```
const p1 = [ 11.6558318, 48.1039072 ]
const p2 = [ 11.6555873, 48.1035817 ]
```